# data.table SD returns as many rows as asked per group with NA fill instead of as many as exist

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am trying to mimic some dplyr code in data.table, which I rarely use. Not getting the result I want.

For example, with dplyr, when I ask for up to 5 rows per group, using `slice`, I get the desired result - as many rows as I ask, or as many exist per group, whichever is lower:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, am) %>%
  slice(1:5)

    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
2  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
3  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
4  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
5  32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
6  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
7  33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
8  27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
9  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
10 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
11 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
12 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
13 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
14 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
15 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
16 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
17 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
18 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
19 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
20 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
21 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
22 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

But, with `data.table` and `.SD`, I get as many rows as I ask, no matter if fewer rows exist per group, and the extra rows are filled with NA in non-grouped columns. Any idea how to get what I get from above `dplyr` code with `data.table`?

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars)[, .SD[1:5], by = .(cyl, am)]
    cyl am  mpg  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs gear carb
 1:   6  1 21.0 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0    4    4
 2:   6  1 21.0 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0    4    4
 3:   6  1 19.7 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0    5    6
 4:   6  1   NA    NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA   NA   NA
 5:   6  1   NA    NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA   NA   NA
 6:   4  1 22.8 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1    4    1
 7:   4  1 32.4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1    4    1
 8:   4  1 30.4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1    4    2
 9:   4  1 33.9  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1    4    1
10:   4  1 27.3  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1    4    1
11:   6  0 21.4 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1    3    1
12:   6  0 18.1 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1    3    1
13:   6  0 19.2 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1    4    4
14:   6  0 17.8 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1    4    4
15:   6  0   NA    NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA   NA   NA
16:   8  0 18.7 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0    3    2
17:   8  0 14.3 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0    3    4
18:   8  0 16.4 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0    3    3
19:   8  0 17.3 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0    3    3
20:   8  0 15.2 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0    3    3
21:   4  0 24.4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1    4    2
22:   4  0 22.8 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1    4    2
23:   4  0 21.5 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1    3    1
24:   4  0   NA    NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA   NA   NA
25:   4  0   NA    NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA   NA   NA
26:   8  1 15.8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0    5    4
27:   8  1 15.0 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0    5    8
28:   8  1   NA    NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA   NA   NA
29:   8  1   NA    NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA   NA   NA
30:   8  1   NA    NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA   NA   NA
    cyl am  mpg  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs gear carb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`slice` automatically readjusts based on the number of rows per group, here we can use `head`.  With `data.table`, indexing if we provide index and the index is greater than the `.N` (i.e. the total number of rows per group), it will create an `NA` row for each index that is outside the range

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars)[, head(.SD, 5), by = .(cyl, am)]
#    cyl am  mpg  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs gear carb
# 1:   6  1 21.0 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0    4    4
# 2:   6  1 21.0 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0    4    4
# 3:   6  1 19.7 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0    5    6
# 4:   4  1 22.8 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1    4    1
# 5:   4  1 32.4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1    4    1
# 6:   4  1 30.4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1    4    2
# 7:   4  1 33.9  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1    4    1
# 8:   4  1 27.3  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1    4    1
# 9:   6  0 21.4 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1    3    1
#10:   6  0 18.1 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1    3    1
#11:   6  0 19.2 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1    4    4
#12:   6  0 17.8 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1    4    4
#13:   8  0 18.7 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0    3    2
#14:   8  0 14.3 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0    3    4
#15:   8  0 16.4 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0    3    3
#16:   8  0 17.3 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0    3    3
#17:   8  0 15.2 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0    3    3
#18:   4  0 24.4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1    4    2
#19:   4  0 22.8 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1    4    2
#20:   4  0 21.5 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1    3    1
#21:   8  1 15.8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0    5    4
#22:   8  1 15.0 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0    5    8
#    cyl am  mpg  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs gear carb
```

---

Also, `slice` should work with `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.table(mtcars)[, slice(.SD, 1:5), by = .(cyl, am)]
```

Comment: Very cool. I like that `slice` solution better because the intent is more obvious when reading the code. Thanks!